# Suppressing error messages

Tags: compiling, errors, warnings

I have a style sheet that has some problems. At this point I am just writing my paper and do not really care about \viiipt warnings and errors. So I need to press enter a million times to skip errors while my latex file is compiling .

Is there any way to tell the compiler (Latex2Pdf) that I want to skip all the errors?

Answer (score 5):

Type `latex --help` and check out -interaction=. An example can look like this:

```
 latex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex
```

Answer (score 4):

Correct the errors directly. At some point in the future you will have an error which completly prevent the generation of the document and then you will have a **very** hard time to get around this problem if you have tons of other error messages still lurking around in your log.

Answer (score 1):

You can use \keepsilent in the preamble. This will suppress all messages as well. However, it is normally best to keep on correcting as you go along.

Comment: `\keepsilent` doesn't seem to be a standard LaTeX macro. Did you mean `\scrollmode`?