# LyX: Suppress errors

Tags: lyx

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2584/suppressing-error-messages), but for LyX: How do I suppress the error messages (so I don't have to press Enter 2000 times to skip over them)? Thank you.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer to the linked question: Correct the errors directly. This is even more important with lyx. Or do you want to rewrite everything when the file no longer gives an output?

Comment: there should be no errors in the document, if you get an error fix it before moving on. (A single error may generate multiple error messages from tex, so ignore all but the first)

Comment: As said above, you're asking the wrong question, the errors should be fixed, not ignored. That said, you probably need to modify some converters in Tools --> Preferences --> File Handling --> Converters. For example, *LaTeX  (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)* is probably the default one.